# IOS OpenGLES, video is cut when landscape mode

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, scaling, landscape

my app(ios8.0) is render streaming video in GLKViewController with Opengl-es

i have a problem that video is cut when landscape mode

> problem capture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SrpF.png

maybe.. i need scaling texture, use vertex shader.

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
    float TexCoordp[2];
} Vertex;

const Vertex Vertices[] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}},
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1}}
};

const GLubyte Indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

#pragma mark - shaders

#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE2(x) STRINGIZE(x)
#define SHADER_STRING(text) @ STRINGIZE2(text)

NSString *const vertexShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
 attribute vec4 Position; // 1
 attribute vec4 SourceColor; // 2

 varying vec4 DestinationColor; // 3

 attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;
 varying vec2 TexCoordOut;

 void main(void) { // 4
     DestinationColor = SourceColor; // 5
     gl_Position = Position; // 6
     TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn; // New
 }
 );
```

setup GL Code

```
- (void)setupGL
{

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // init the update render semaphore
    _textureUpdateRenderSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create((long)1);

}
```

maybe i need change "Vertices", but i can't get any clue.

thank you so much for your help

Comment: i success scaling!!!!, but still video is cut. maybe "GLKView" cannot change landscape mode. why can't change GLKView..?

Comment: Surprising that you are still struggling with it. Why don't you follow the way that I told you? It is the easiest way :) to put one matrix in the vertex shader    and you need not to change the orientation of any view wrapping the OpenGL view